# After upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04 I'm getting minimal graphics problem

Tags: 12.04, graphics

I've updated 10.04 to 12.04 recently using do release command but now it says minimal  graphics problem. Internet is  not working due to which I can't download from Internet.

How to update graphics in this case?

Answer (score 0):

restart ubuntu in recovery mode, then automatically opens recovery menu, select repair broken packages, press enter. its a long process, asks permission to continue many time, then press "y " n enter. it will find out the broken file and ask you for update, just press "y", then enter. this worked for me. try all the best